# Last one to the camping site has to do the cooking

Tags: word-usage

What will be a natural way to increase the length of "last one to. "?

Two people are racing to the camping site in their cars.  So one of them says:

> Last one to the camping site has to do the cooking.

Can it be:

> The person who gets there last has to do the cooking.

Is it correct to use it this way?

Answer (score 3):

Correct in grammar perhaps, but the idiom is "Last one to the ...", and your alternative sounds very stilted, nobody would actually use it.  There are lots of ways you can challenge a person to a race.

> If I beat you to the campsite you'll have to do the cooking. Okay?

Note, racing in cars on the public road is illegal.

Comment: @TypelA are you likely to use "Whoever get there last has to do the cooking".

Comment: I would say "last one [there] has to cook." As this answer states, it is a perfectly natural and idiomatic expression. No need to change it. As for what the winner says, a simple "You're it!" would do nicely.

Comment: But will this change still sound okay...  (Though there's no need to change it?..  I just want to know)  @TypelA. (Whoever get there last will have to cook)

Comment: And what about:  "I got here first"..... " You got here last". And "I was the first one to get here"..... " You were the last one to get here" @TypelA

Comment: What do you think @TypelA?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish In what context are you placing the alternatives? They are all *grammatical* and understandable, but none seems as common, idiomatic, or natural to me as the simple *last one . . .something* formation. That is what people say more than anything else; there is little point in changing it.

Comment: What about these ones @JasonBassford: "I got here first"..... " You got here last". And "I was the first one to get here"..... " You were the last one to get here". (These aren't alternatives...)  I am just asking whether in different contexts they'll sound natural.  As in when you get to a place,  you exclaim "I got here first! " or "I am the first one to get here".

Comment: And @JasonBassford if there are a couple of people and a person is instructing them (Not being excited just telling the instructions)  "The person who gets there first has to ______" Or "The first person to get  there _______". Or " Whoever gets there first has to ______" .And " The person who gets there last has to _____" Or "The last one to get there has to ______" Or "Whoever gets there last has to ______"

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Please limit yourself to a single type of question. If you want to know about what sounds natural as an expression *after the fact*, rather than ahead of time as in the question itself, that seems like a separate question to me. It is *definitely* too broad to be addressed in comments. As for all other phrases you give regarding the future, that's already been asked and answered. (There is no point in bringing up hundreds of alternatives and asking about each individually.)